# Why is an adverb not an adjective used?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

In the sentence:
He did not pass the course as easily as he thought he would.

1. Why is easily (an adverb) used?
2. Why is easy (adjective) not correct?

Answer (score 6):

Adjectives modify (describe) nouns and pronouns. Adverbs modify verbs, adjectives and other adverbs.

> The course was not easy.

*course*, *easy*: "course" is a noun, so we use an adjective.

> He thought he would pass it easily.
>   He did not pass it easily.
>   He did not pass the course as easily as he thought he would.

*pass*, *easily*: "pass" here is a verb, so we use an adverb.

Answer (score 3):

I know that *easily* comes after *the course*, which is a noun and might make you think it should be followed by the adjective *easy*, but ask yourself what was not done as easily as thought.

The answer is *pass*. *Pass* is a verb, so it is correctly modified by an adverb.

Answer (score 1):

It directly modifies the verb *pass*, hence it should be an adverb. It is not modifying a noun.

On a similar note though, modern speakers are notoriously bad at using adjectives where adverbs would be better. Undoubtedly you hear people use adjectives in a similar functional role often. Technically it is not good grammar.

Answer (score 0):

"He did not easily pass the course as he thought he would," is a positive statement.  The construction above is a pseudo comparative form.  It compares what he thought would happen to what actually happened. This makes the grammar somewhat confusing. A more simple and direct statement would be:  "The course was harder for him than he thought it would be."